# How to access drop down list field type selected value in sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I can access Single-Line text field type by following in Repeater:

```
<sc:FieldRenderer ID="frTitle" runat="server" 
    FieldName="Title" 
    Item="<%# (Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)Container.DataItem %>" />
```

but how to access drop-down list field type selected value defined in item.

Thanks

Comment: What field type are you using, DropList or DropLink?

Comment: It's field type is DropLink

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This depends on the exact field type you are using.

### If using a `Droplist` field type

The value is stored in Sitecore as plain text representing the name* of the selected item. In this case you could use your code sample to render out the name of the selected item (if that's really what you want to do).  *Note that the content editor will see the Display Name of the items in the droplist, but your code would render out the item name. Using this field type is not usually a good idea as it is not possible to translate item names.

### If using a `DropTree` or `Droplink` field type

The value is stored in Sitecore is an ID of the linked item.  In this case you would need to get the selected item using this ID, then render out the required field of that item.  I would probably write a code-behind method to get the selected item, then call this method within your FieldRenderer.  Something like this:

Code-behind:

```
public Item GetLinkedItem(Item item, string itemField)
{
    string dropDownItemId = item[itemField];
    return Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(dropDownItemId);
}
```

Ascx markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptChildren" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <sc:FieldRenderer ID="frTitle" runat="server"
            FieldName="Title"
            Item='<%# GetLinkedItem((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)Container.DataItem, "YourDropLinkFieldName") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: So Sitecore proposes us a DropList field that shouldn't be used and does not work as one would expect (display display name and not name)... ?

Comment: Sitecore just provides the different field types. It is up to you to chose which one to use. They each have their pros and cons. In most cases, DropTree or Droplink is the better choice, but there are certainly cases where it makes more sense to use Droplist as you can avoid needing to retrieve items via the api, just to get the "value".