# How we save and retrive selected value of droplist programmatically in sitecore

Tags: sitecore

How we save and retrive selected value of droplist my template programmatically in sitecore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access drop down list field type selected value in sitecore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24633156/how-to-access-drop-down-list-field-type-selected-value-in-sitecore)

Comment: While I think it's a duplicate, Mariam, you might be asking a different question? It is unclear based on how you asked. Please add some clarification as to what you are trying to achieve, code sample you have if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For saving Droplist value you can use this code

```
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item sampleItem=Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/home/sample");

if (sampleItem!=null)
{
   sampleItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
   sampleItem.Fields["DroplIst Field Name"].Value = "Value to be saved in droplist";
   sampleItem.Editing.EndEdit();
}
```